# Mysql query taking too much time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using a query in my sql. First i used

```
SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME(`points`.`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `date`,
    (SELECT  COALESCE(SUM(`points`.`votes`),0) FROM `points`
     WHERE `type` = 1 AND `server_id` = 24 AND
           FROM_UNIXTIME(`points`.`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d') = `date`) AS `votes_count`
FROM `points`
WHERE `points`.`timestamp` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND
      `server_id` = 24
GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY `date`";
```

It is too slow taking around 30 sec. My table is 
[image]

What can I do make it faster than 2 sec

Comment: Are your columns indexed? Check it by using `desc table_name;` Are the index being used? Check it by using `explain <your_query>;`

Comment: can you explain why is this `FROM_UNIXTIME(`points`.`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d') = 'date'` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `date`,
    SUM (CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN votes ELSE 0 END) AS votes_count
FROM points
WHERE `timestamp` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND
      server_id = 24
GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER BY `date`
```

Here I removed the unnecessary correlated subquery in your `SELECT` statement.  It appears that you just want to conditionally sum votes when the `type` is `1`.  If so, then use conditional aggregation in the form of a `CASE` statement.

If this change doesn't get you fast enough, then consider adding indices on the `timestamp` and `server_id` columns.  Adding such indices should allow the `WHERE` clause to execute more efficiently.

As a final note, please avoid using keywords for naming your columns, e.g. `date` and `timestamp`.  While they are not *reserved* keywords, they still have a special meaning in the context of, e.g., creating a new table.